# Pytest: customize test discovery through command line

Tags: unit-testing, testing, pytest

There are ways to configure pytest test discovery through [configuration file](https://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/example/pythoncollection.html#changing-naming-conventions) .

I wonder if there are ways to configure pytest test discovery through command line options/args. In other words, can  I just pass some argument/switch to pytest command to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every entry you put in the config file (so-called "inioption") can be passed from command line using the `-o/--override-ini` option. The `-o` option can be applied multiple times. E.g.

```
$ pytest -o python_files='check_*.py' \
         -o python_classes=Check \
         -o python_functions='*_check'
```

Source: [Configuration Options](https://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/reference/reference.html#configuration-options).